# How to expand he variadic parameters from derived class to base in initialization list in a lambda expression using VS2013 (C++)

Tags: c++

I tried to research this on-line for a while, I found nothing about this kind of question. I thought this may be caused by the compiler of VS2013 (v130)

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
class Base {

public:
    Base(const std::function<void()> f)
         :_f(f) {
    }
    void Set (const std::function<void()> f) {_f=f;}
    void Run () {
         _f();
    }
protected:
    Base() = default;
private:

    std::function<void()> _f;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    template<typename P, typename C, typename ... Pas, typename ... Args>
    Derived(P object, void(C::* method)(Pas ...), Args&& ... args)
        :Base ([=]()-> void { ((*object).*method)(args ...); })
   {

   // Set ([=]()-> void { ((*object).*method)(args ...); });
    }
};

class Foo {

public:
     void bar(int a, double b)
     {
       std::cout << "a: " <<a << ", b: " <<b <<std::endl;
     }

};


int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  int c =10;
  double d =10.0;
  Derived t(&foo, &Foo::bar,c,d);

  t.Run();
}
```

if I want to initialize the base class using the lambda expression in initialization list, 
when compile it, the compiler vs130 will give serval errors, one of related to this,
  error C2065: 'args' : undeclared identifier

the workaround is using  "Set" function instead.
but I want to know, is there anyway to just use the initialization list.

Comment: What does "it would not be compiled" mean? Did you run your compiler?

Comment: Well you're [obviously missing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f5d281b3af6285e) some `#include` statements in your example. What's your question actually?

Comment: it means the compiler will complain with errors;  error C2065: 'args' : undeclared identifier

Comment: @ryan Post the verbatim error message in your question, if you want to get helped to fix them. Voted to close your question for missing that now.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce any problems](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41e51284822d3411).

Comment: it is not because the includes

Comment: I use VS 2013 (vs130), not g++

Comment: could someone build it using VS 2013?

Comment: is this supported by C11?

Comment: This is indeed a problem in Visual C++ 2013, [reported on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1230353) and fixed in VC++ 2015 (at least I can confirm that your code works fine in 2015 Update 2). A workaround for your specific case (if you don't want to do something fancier in that lambda) is to use `std::bind(method, object, args...)` instead.

Comment: @bogdan, thank your for the  explanation